# Likelihood of a Poisson-described event to occur in the next second

Tags: density-function, likelihood, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

Consider a recurring event for which the time periods between consecutive events is exponentially distributed. For argument's sake, I'm waiting for a taxi on a busy street. **How might one calculate the likelihood of a taxi showing up in the next second?**

Intuitively the chance that the event will occur in the next second should be just **the integral of the PDF over the range** `(NOW, NOW+1)`. However, the fact that I am waiting for the event during this time period is **not independent** of the fact that the event did **not** occur in the time period `(0, NOW]`. Thus, perhaps I should consider the the integral of the PDF over the range `[0, NOW+1)` to get the probability of the event to occur in the next second. Though this "feels wrong" it does make sense as for each given second, the likelihood of the event occurring in that second is higher than it will be for the following second, *given that the event has not already occurred*.

Comment: if the tax arrivak process really is a poisson process, so the waiting time really is exponential, you have the memoryless propert.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen. Correct, memoryless.

Comment: You have been waiting since `NOW` for a taxi. Whether any taxis arrived before `NOW` is irrelevant since you were not present. The probability that a taxi arrives before time `NOW+1` is the integral of the pdf from $0$ to $1$, not from `NOW` to `NOW+1`.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Are you are suggesting that every time period has an equal likelihood of observing a taxi arriving (possibly due to the memoryless property)? If so, that would be an argument that Poisson processes are described by the uniform distribution, not the exponential distribution.

Comment: No, the calculation $\int_0^1 \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx = 1-e^{-\lambda}$ gives the probability that _at least_ one taxi arrives in the time interval $(0,1]$ or `(NOW, NOW+1]` or $(t, t+1]$ etc. The _total_ number of taxis arriving in this interval is a Poisson$(\lambda)$ random variable $N$; $P(N=0)=e^{-\lambda}$, $P(N>0)=1-e^{-\lambda}$, $P(N=1)=\lambda e^{-\lambda}$ etc. It is also true that **conditioned on exactly one arrival in $(0,1]$,** the _time_ of arrival is (conditionally) uniformly distributed on $(0,1]$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Thank you, you have given me ideas for some things to google for. However, I do stress that the time period `(0,1]` is arbitrary: it could be one minute, one second, or one decade. Thus I do not believe that the time of arrival is uniformly distributed, but I concede that I'm probably wrong. I'm googling now, but if you have a good resource that explains it I would love a link. You could put the link in an answer and if it gets the idea through my skull I'll happily accept it! Thank you.

Comment: @dotancohen Please pay careful attention to the **boldface** text in my comment: I didn't say that the time of arrival is uniformly distributed on $(0,1]$ but rather that **given that there is exactly one arrival in $(0,1]$,** the time of arrival is **conditionally uniformly distributed on $(0,1]$** which is not quite the same thing. You may want to take a look at [this answer of mine](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/137618/6633) for some additional ideas about Poisson processes.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I think that I see our discrepancy, I apologize for not having noticed it earlier. I have been waiting since T=0 for a taxi (not since T=NOW as you mention in your first comment). At this moment, NOW time units after T=0, I ponder what is the likelihood that a taxi will appear soon. For sake of setting, let us assume that I will light a cigarette if the likelihood of a taxi arriving is <50% during the next 1 time unit. When do I light the cigarette, if ever?

Comment: @dotancohen It doesn't matter whether you were waiting from $t=0$ or $t = $ `6 pm, October 22, 4004 B.C.`. Since you are _still_ waiting at $t =$ `NOW`, no taxis have arrived since the time you began waiting until `NOW`. The probability that _no_ taxis arrive in the next second is $e^{-\lambda/60}$ where $\lambda$ is the _average_ number of taxis that arrive in one minute. All this is true regardless of when you began waiting (as long as you are still awaiting a taxi arrival till `NOW` whenever that `NOW` is.